# iphone sdk - poker odds calculation

Tags: iphone, analyzer, poker

i'm playing with xcode to create a poker hand analizer. 
I've used the specialK hand evaluator.
after included the evaluator in my project i've detached two threads ( with 125k cycles each ) to attempt to run monte carlo simulation in order to check percentage of winning for each player... my problem is that 125k x 2 cycles takes about 40 seconds to run on an iphone 4. does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't do Monte Carlo on an iPhone. Not a nice answer, but I think it's correct.

Comment: Uhm... i'm about to agree with you.. montecarlo is too slow.. suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried comparing the percentages derived from runs at 125K simulations versus those derived from smaller runs, say 5K or 10K?  It's possible the percentages converge closely enough for practical purposes.

Comment: not yet i have to say... i thought that more simulations i do better and closer to the reality is the result... i will test with less simulations and post the results... thanks